# Data appearing twice in array - Swift(SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swiftui

```
class DataHandler: ObservableObject{
@Published var HomePagePosts = [Post]()
@Published var loggedInUser = UserObject()

init() {
    self.loadHomePagePosts()
}

func loadHomePagePosts(){
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    
    ref.child("Posts").observe(.value) { post in
        for entry in post.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            guard let dict = entry.value as? [String: AnyObject] else {return}
            self.HomePagePosts.append(handlePostDictionary(dict))
            self.HomePagePosts.sort(by: {$0.date!.compare($1.date!) == .orderedDescending})
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my code for the homepage loading the posts

```
@ObservedObject var dataHandler: DataHandler
            ForEach(self.dataHandler.HomePagePosts, id: \.id, content:{
                post in
                EntryCell(currentPost: post)
                
            })
```

Here is my main datahandler. Essentially, the problem is that if I post to my server on firebase, and I go to my homepage, it will re-render the posts and add it to the array of posts(HomePagePosts), duplicating every post except for the new one. I tried just making the array blank at the start of the function, but now I can only see one post when I click on the home page. Thanks so much for taking the time to read the question, any suggestions?

Comment: Off topic but don’t sort the array for each item added, sort after the `for` loop instead

Comment: Thanks! I just changed that, hopefully that speeds up the function a bit.

Comment: What about adding the the download posts to a local array variable and then after the loop assign that array to self.HomePagePosts?

Comment: Take a look at the loop - it iterates over every post node returned from firebase, appends it to an array, sorts the array (over and over) then appends another post etc. Best to populate the array *then* sort it. Also, why sort in code? Keep two copies of the date data in each node, one + and one - values and then order by that node to have the ascending or descending. TIP: don't capitalize var names, use lowercase. Uppercase are for Class and Structure definitions. Also, .observe adds an observer so if there's a change in Firebase ALL of the data will be reloaded and appended to the array.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! What I did to fix the issue was I moved out the sort function and just cleared the array before the for loop. Hopefully, there are no efficiency issues with this, it seems to not slow down the loading too much.